# I scraped data using the Reddit API praw in Python, but characters like ' show up as â€™t. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, screen-scraping, praw

I'm very new to Python (And StackOverflow, so excuse me if I'm doing this wrong). i scraped submissions from the /r/loseit subreddit, so I could clean it and make a wordcloud in R for an assignment. The scraping went fine, however special characters are showing up as garbage, for instance the following sentence:

"Aâ€™LL I think Iâ€™ve broken the plateau and Iâ€™m.."

My code:

```
import praw



#Set up app
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='removed',
                     client_secret='removed',
                     user_agent='removed')


#Import pandas library as pd
import pandas as pd

#Make empty dataset
posts = []

#Function to scrape body for textposts and append to posts. We only want textposts, any other data is not necessary.
li_subreddit = reddit.subreddit('LoseIt')
for post in li_subreddit.new(limit=1000):
    posts.append([post.selftext])
posts = pd.DataFrame(posts,columns=['body'])
posts


#Save as csv
posts.to_csv('loseit2.csv')
```

Comment: I ran your code and the special characters appear correctly when opened in my text editor and when opened in Apple Numbers. So there is not a problem in your script. The problem is in whatever software you're using to open and display the resulting CSV.

Comment: I'm using R to import it. is also shows it in excel

Answer (score 0):

**Mojibake** !!

The most interesting kind of brokenness that [**ftfy**](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will fix is when someone has encoded Unicode with one standard and decoded it with a different one. This often shows up as characters that turn into nonsense sequences (called “mojibake”):

- The word **schön** might appear as **schÃ¶n**.
- An em dash (—) might appear as **â€”**.
- Text that was meant to be enclosed in quotation marks might end up instead enclosed in **â€œ** and **â€<9d>**, where **<9d>** represents an unprintable character.

Install "Fix Text For You" like so; `pip3 install ftfy`
And use it as follow;

```
import ftfy

# this will fix your encoding problem
posts['body'] = posts['body'].map(ftfy.fix_encoding)
```